# Как в PyQt5 передать параметры в функцию при клике на кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyqt5

Есть код:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, sz * 13, sz * 17)
        self.setWindowTitle('Игра')
        self.field = [[], [], []]
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                self.field[i].append(QPushButton('', self))
                self.field[i][j].resize(sz * 3, sz * 3)
                self.field[i][j].move(sz + 4 * i * sz, 3 * sz + j * 4 * sz)
                self.field[i][j].clicked.connect(self.step)

    def step(self, button):
        print(button.text())
        if button.text() == '':
            if button.step:
                button.setText('X')
            else:
                button.setText('O')
```

При клике на field[i][j] я хочу вызвать функцию step, которая должна поменять текст в кнопке на которую я нажал. Но для этого мне нужно либо знать i и j для этой кнопки либо передавать в функцию саму кнопку. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Кст, что не QGridLayout'ом разместили кнопки? Так удобнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут есть несколько проблем:

- Сигнал кнопки [clicked](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) имеет такую сигнатуру: `clicked(bool checked = false)`, т.е. он отсылает параметр. Поэтому у вас с ошибкой падает, т.к. у `bool` нет атрибута `text`
- Это `button.step` не рабочее, у кнопки такого поля нет. Лучше завести такое поле у класса и менять в функции
- Чтобы передавать состояние при клике нужно использовать лямбды

Решение:

- Для `button.step` завел счетчик `self._step = 0`, и по его кратности определяем кто ходит
- Функция обработки клика теперь выглядит так: `def _on_clicked_cell(self, button, i, j):`. На всякий случай оставил возможность получения индексов.
- Вместо указания ссылки на метод для `connect`, создается лямбда: `lambda checked, button=button, i=i, j=j: self._on_clicked_cell(button, i, j)`. Параметры: `checked` -- это значение, что сигнал передаст, а остальные -- предопределенные параметры, что будут переданы при клике в `_on_clicked_cell`

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi()

        self._step = 0

    def setupUi(self):
        sz = 15  # Магическое число

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, sz * 13, sz * 17)
        self.setWindowTitle('Игра')
        self.field = [[], [], []]

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                button = QPushButton('', self)
                self.field[i].append(button)
                self.field[i][j].resize(sz * 3, sz * 3)
                self.field[i][j].move(sz + 4 * i * sz, 3 * sz + j * 4 * sz)
                self.field[i][j].clicked.connect(
                    lambda checked, button=button, i=i, j=j: self._on_clicked_cell(button, i, j)
                )

    def _on_clicked_cell(self, button, i, j):
        print(button.text(), i, j)
        if button.text():
            return

        if self._step % 2 == 0:
            button.setText('X')
        else:
            button.setText('O')

        self._step += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

**PS.**

Пример с размещением кнопок на `QGridLayout`:

```
    def setupUi(self):
        sz = 15  # Магическое число

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, sz * 13, sz * 17)
        self.setWindowTitle('Игра')

        layout = QGridLayout()

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                button = QPushButton('')
                button.setFixedSize(sz * 3, sz * 3)
                button.clicked.connect(
                    lambda checked, button=button, i=i, j=j: self._on_clicked_cell(button, i, j)
                )

                layout.addWidget(button, i, j)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
```

А так, я бы еще посоветовал посмотреть в сторону `QGraphicsScene`

Comment: я бы в первом примере список `self.field` убрал, т.к. рябит в глазах от `[ ]` скобок :)

Comment: @S.Nick, да пусть остается, возможно у автора был какой-то план на эту матрицу :)